# ¿Cómo logro que en una lista, python muestre lo que pido?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy realizando un algoritmo para almacenar cierta información por medio de seriales, luego, por medio de un ciclo for, pido a python que me muestre el serial que le pida. Sin embargo, me imprime mas, porque también me imprime el `else`

```
elif menu == '2':
        info = input("Ingresar el código serial de la pipeta a buscar: ")
        for i in lab:
            if i[1] == info:
                print('\nMarca: {a}'.format(a=i[0]))
                print('Serial: {a}'.format(a=i[1]))
                print('\nMedición 1: ', i[2][0], "uL")
                print('Medición 2: ', i[2][1], "uL")
                print('Medición 3: ', i[2][2], "uL")
                print('La media que resulta de estas mediciones es: ', media11, 'uL')
                print('\nMedición 4: ', i[3][0], "uL")
                print('Medición 5: ', i[3][1], "uL")
                print('Medición 6: ', i[3][2], "uL")
                print('La media que resulta de estas mediciones es: ', media12, 'uL')
            else:
                    print("El código serial no ha sido encontrado. Verifique la información proporcionada")
```

¿Cómo logro que solo me imprima lo que es verdadero, o en caso de ser falso, solo lo falso y además una sola vez?

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la forma en que estás formulando el *loop*. Si tienes 10 labs y pides un serial que existe, vas a ver en pantalla 1 vez la info y 9 veces el *else*.

Una forma fácil de solucionarlo es usar un *flag* y sacar el *else* de tu bucle:

```
elif menu == '2':
        info = input("Ingresar el código serial de la pipeta a buscar: ")
        encontrado = False
        for i in lab:
            if i[1] == info:
                print('\nMarca: {a}'.format(a=i[0]))
                print('Serial: {a}'.format(a=i[1]))
                print('\nMedición 1: ', i[2][0], "uL")
                print('Medición 2: ', i[2][1], "uL")
                print('Medición 3: ', i[2][2], "uL")
                print('La media que resulta de estas mediciones es: ', media11, 'uL')
                print('\nMedición 4: ', i[3][0], "uL")
                print('Medición 5: ', i[3][1], "uL")
                print('Medición 6: ', i[3][2], "uL")
                print('La media que resulta de estas mediciones es: ', media12, 'uL')
                encontrado = True
                break
            

        if encontrado == False:
            print("El código serial no ha sido encontrado. Verifique la información proporcionada")
```

Saludos

Comment: Un `for-else` te ahorraría la variable booleana.

Comment: Lo que me choca es la comparación `if encontrado == false`, encuentro mucho más elegante (y natural) `if not encontrado`